# React form using data from previous input

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api, use-state

I'm working with react and a weather API and have put together this form:

```js
function Forecast() {
  const [cities, setCities] = React.useState([]);

  const addCity = (city) => {
    if (!city.text || /^\s*$/.test(city.text)) {
      return;
    }

    const newCities = [city, ...cities];

    setCities(newCities);
  };

  const removeCity = (id) => {
    const removedArray = [...cities].filter((city) => city.id !== id);

    setCities(removedArray);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Form onSubmit={addCity} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Form = (props) => {
  const api = {
    key: "39471307bd579e5ce6b1d89dc164dd77",
    base: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/",
  };

  const [input, setInput] = React.useState("");
  const [weather, setWeather] = React.useState({});
  const [query, setQuery] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${input}&appid=${api.key}&units=metric`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => setWeather(result));

    props.onSubmit({
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
      text: input,
      data: weather,
    });

    setInput("");
  };

  return (
    <form className="search-container" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter City"
        name="text"
        value={input}
        className="search"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <button className="add-card-button">
        <i className="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Forecast />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

When I'm testing this, the first time you search for a city it's returning no data and the second time you search, it's using the input from the first search as so on. Does anyone know how can I get it so that the first search returns data immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch()` is *asynchronous*. You have to set your weather data *after* the API call finishes.

Furthermore, you have to make sure to use the fresh `result` (calling `setWeather(result)` doesn't update `weather` immediately).

Edit `handleSubmit` to something like this:

```js
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${input}&appid=${api.key}&units=metric`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        props.onSubmit({
          id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
          text: input,
          data: result,
        });
        setWeather(result);
        setInput("");
      });
  };
```

### Resources:

- [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)
- [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

### Full code:

```js
function Forecast() {
  const [cities, setCities] = React.useState([]);

  const addCity = (city) => {
    if (!city.text || /^\s*$/.test(city.text)) {
      return;
    }

    const newCities = [city, ...cities];
    console.log(newCities);
    setCities(newCities);
  };

  const removeCity = (id) => {
    const removedArray = [...cities].filter((city) => city.id !== id);

    setCities(removedArray);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Form onSubmit={addCity} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Form = (props) => {
  const api = {
    key: "39471307bd579e5ce6b1d89dc164dd77",
    base: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/",
  };

  const [input, setInput] = React.useState("");
  const [weather, setWeather] = React.useState({});
  const [query, setQuery] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${input}&appid=${api.key}&units=metric`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        props.onSubmit({
          id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
          text: input,
          data: result,
        });
        setWeather(result);
        setInput("");
      });
  };

  return (
    <form className="search-container" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter City"
        name="text"
        value={input}
        className="search"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <button className="add-card-button">
        <i className="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Forecast />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

useRef hook works well with forms. assign a useRef hook variable to the form

remove !!

```
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState("");
```

replace

```
const input = useRef('')
```

input tag

```
 <input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Enter City"
    name="text"
    ref={input}
    className="search"
  />
```

submit function

```
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${input.current.value}&appid=${api.key}&units=metric`)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((result) => setWeather(result));

props.onSubmit({
  id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
  text: input.current.value,
  data: weather,
});

input.current.value = '';
```

};

Comment: You've just replaced a normal state variable with a ref which solves absolutely nothing. You haven't explained your approach. Your code blocks are not properly indented.

Answer (score -1):

I cant code right now. But try putting the fetch inside a useEffect hook. And trigger the effect somehow after the submit. With a condicional inside or something. Maybe passing the state as a dependency of the useEffect.

Maybe tomorrow i can send a proper propose for your code

Comment: That's not the problem here. `handleSubmit()` (and `fetch()` in turn) **does** get called when the form is submitted.